# vendored/submodule gems with warbler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, tomcat, jruby, warbler

How can this be done?  Here's my best effort:

Specify gems with path.  This causes warnings:

```
warning: Bundler `path' components are not currently supported.
The `acts_as_api-0.3.11' component was not bundled.
Your application may fail to boot!
```

The app almost boots, giving this error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Other ideas, with varying degrees of crapitude:
 - remove/rename .git when before warbling
 - deploy to github, use git: option.  Tried this, but problematic as it looks like branch: option wasn't read.  Didn't delve.
 - Try and sneak the gems in to `config.gem_path = "WEB-INF/vendor/bundler_gems"` ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendored gems seem to work nonetheless.